# stem not recognizing tor's path

Tags: python, tor, stem

While running Stem's To Russia With Love example, I got the following error:

> 'tor' isn't available on your system. Maybe it's not in your PATH

To solve this, I added the following path to tor_cmd as shown in the example over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805260/tor-name-not-recognized-in-stem):

```
tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  tor_cmd = '~/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor',
  config = {
    'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
    'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
  },
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)
```

However, its now giving me the error:

> OSError: '~/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor'
>   doesn't exist

when it clearly does. I am adding the snapshot of the listed files in the folder path:
[image]

Could anyone please help me resolve this problem? Thanks.

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` character is a Bash shell feature that expands to the value of the environment variable `$HOME`.  It doesn't work in Python or other programming languages.

Instead, specify the the full path to Tor, or create a link to it somewhere in the `$PATH` Python is using in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually tried doing this but its now giving me a completely different error: `File "practice.py", line 49, in <module> init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/process.py", line 266, in launch_tor_with_config
    return launch_tor(tor_cmd, args, torrc_path, completion_percent, init_msg_handler, timeout, take_ownership)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/process.py", line 143, in launch_tor
    raise OSError('Process terminated: %s' % last_problem)
OSError: Process terminated: Timed out`

Comment: Do you think you could help? Or maybe I should create a separate post for it?

Comment: Just created a new post over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571423/running-stem-with-tor-gives-process-terminated-timed-out).